# Unable to display message when account is flagged

Tags: 8, theming, users, flags

I have this code in my sub theme :

**bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_id = 'flag_role_association';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_association'] = $flag_status;

  $flag_id = 'flag_role_pop_up_store';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_pop_up_store'] = $flag_status;

  $flag_id = 'flag_role_artisan';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag);
  $variables['is_flagged_role_artisan'] = $flag_status;
}
```

And this templates :

**user--account-roles.html.twig**

```
<div class="card p-4 overflow-hidden shadow rounded bg-white">

  <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
    <p class="text-center">Vous trouverez sur cette page les différents types de compte disponible.</p>
    <p class="text-center">Chaque type de compte vous donne droit à des autorisations au sein de la plateforme.</p>
    <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Vous devez avoir un numéro de SIRET.</p>
    <p class="text-center">Les modifications peuvent prendre 24 heures pour ếtre appliquées.</p>
  </div>

  <p>Les associations sont destinées aux comités des fêtes, offices de tourisme, ... qui organisent des événements. Vous pourrez y publier divers types de contenu.</p>
  {% if 'association' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte association est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte association est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte association est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_association }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Les boutiques éphémères vous permettent d'exposer les créations des artisans présents sur la plateforme (pas de vente en ligne).</p>
  {% if 'pop_up_store' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_pop_up_store }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Si vous êtes artisans, nous serions ravis de vous accueillir sur notre marketplace. Nous facturons une commission de 10% sur chaque vente. Vous recevrez une facture à chaque début de mois, si vous réalisez des ventes le mois précédent. Plus d'infos sur <a href="/node/271">cette page</a>.</p>
  <p>Pas de vente = Rien à payer</p>
  {% if 'marchand' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte artisan est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte artisan est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte artisan est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_artisan }}
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

When I go to a user account page, I have a blank page where it says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

In my Drupal logs, I have the PHP error below.

How can I correct this ?

```
Type    php
Date    Vendredi, 6 novembre, 2020 - 04:25
Utilisateur administrateur
Emplacement https://dev.example.com/user/1
Référent    
Message TypeError : Argument 1 passed to Drupal\flag\FlagService::getFlagging() must implement interface Drupal\flag\FlagInterface, null given, called in /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme on line 11 dans Drupal\flag\FlagService->getFlagging() (/home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/modules/contrib/flag/src/FlagService.php ligne 84)
#0 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme(11): Drupal\flag\FlagService->getFlagging()
#1 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(287): bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user()
#2 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(431): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render()
#3 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(200): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
#4 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(226): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
#5 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
#6 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(227): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
#7 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(117): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare()
#8 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse()
#9 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray()
#10 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func()
#11 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(156): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch()
#12 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
#13 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
#14 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle()
#15 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle()
#16 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass()
#17 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle()
#18 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle()
#19 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle()
#20 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle()
#21 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(708): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle()
#22 /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle()
#23 {main}
.
Severity    Erreur
```

These are "Global" flags, here is the machine name (screenshot). Only the end of the machine name changes depending on the type of flag.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to implement three times your flag service, once is enough (same for your user to flag).

The error says `Message TypeError : Argument 1 passed to Drupal\flag\FlagService::getFlagging() must implement interface Drupal\flag\FlagInterface, null given` which means your `$flag` variable is null. Most likely the flag service is unable to retrieve a flag for the flag ids you're giving (`flag_role_association`, `flag_role_pop_up_store`, `flag_role_artisan`). Are you sure about those values ?

I would personnaly rewrite your hook as follow ; it should remove the error and display the page but I am not sure it will completely solve your problem as long as `$flag` will be null.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];

  $flag_ids = [
    'flag_role_association' => 'is_flagged_role_association',
    'flag_role_pop_up_store' => 'is_flagged_role_pop_up_store',
    'flag_role_artisan' => 'is_flagged_role_artisan',
  ];

  foreach ($flag_ids as $flag_id => $var_flag) {
    if ($flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id)) {
      if ($flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag)) {
        $variables[$var_flag] = $flag_status;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this. I updated the end of my question. Yet my machine name seems to match.

Comment: Ok it works thank you. You just have to remove flag_ at the start of the machine name.

Comment: I was about to say that in the screenshot you added there was no `flag_` in the machine name :}

Comment: Sorry, I'm relaunching my question because it only works for the first condition. For the other 2, the icon does not turn orange. I added a screenshot at the end of my question.

Comment: Ok it works, the problem is that the code is cached. How can I turn off the cache for this page ?

Comment: You should create a new topic and ask how to disable the cache on a user page or how to add flags to cache contexts which would clear the cache when there's a new flag action.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a new question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297991/how-to-update-the-twig-flag-conditions