# How to update the TWIG flag conditions?

Tags: 8, theming, users, caching, flags

I have this code in my sub theme :

**bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];

  $flag_ids = [
    'role_association' => 'is_flagged_role_association',
    'role_pop_up_store' => 'is_flagged_role_pop_up_store',
    'role_artisan' => 'is_flagged_role_artisan',
  ];

  foreach ($flag_ids as $flag_id => $var_flag) {
    if ($flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id)) {
      if ($flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag)) {
        $variables[$var_flag] = $flag_status;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this templates :

**user--account-roles.html.twig**

```
<div class="card p-4 overflow-hidden shadow rounded bg-white">

  <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
    <p class="text-center">Vous trouverez sur cette page les différents types de compte disponible.</p>
    <p class="text-center">Chaque type de compte vous donne droit à des autorisations au sein de la plateforme.</p>
    <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Vous devez avoir un numéro de SIRET.</p>
    <p class="text-center">Les modifications peuvent prendre 24 heures pour ếtre appliquées.</p>
  </div>

  <p>Les associations sont destinées aux comités des fêtes, offices de tourisme, ... qui organisent des événements. Vous pourrez y publier divers types de contenu.</p>
  {% if 'association' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte association est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte association est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'association' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_association %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte association est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_association }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Les boutiques éphémères vous permettent d'exposer les créations des artisans présents sur la plateforme (pas de vente en ligne).</p>
  {% if 'pop_up_store' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'pop_up_store' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_pop_up_store %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte boutique éphémère est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_pop_up_store }}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="border-top mt-4 mb-4"></span>

  <p>Si vous êtes artisans, nous serions ravis de vous accueillir sur notre marketplace. Nous facturons une commission de 10% sur chaque vente. Vous recevrez une facture à chaque début de mois, si vous réalisez des ventes le mois précédent. Plus d'infos sur <a href="/node/271">cette page</a>.</p>
  <p>Pas de vente = Rien à payer</p>
  {% if 'marchand' in user.getroles %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Votre compte artisan est actif.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> Votre compte artisan est en attente.</div>
  {% elseif 'marchand' not in user.getroles and not is_flagged_role_artisan %}
    <div><i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> Votre compte artisan est inactif.</div>
    {{ content.flag_role_artisan }}
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

The above code works but the problem is that it is cached. I have to face `drush cr` for the conditions in TWIG to be visible in my page.

How can I correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/2568131#comment-11299071), something like the following might do the trick:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for user.html.twig.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $user_to_flag = $variables['user'];

  $flag_ids = [
    'role_association' => 'is_flagged_role_association',
    'role_pop_up_store' => 'is_flagged_role_pop_up_store',
    'role_artisan' => 'is_flagged_role_artisan',
  ];
  
  $invalidate_cache = FALSE;
  foreach ($flag_ids as $flag_id => $var_flag) {
    if ($flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id)) {
      if ($flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag)) {
        $variables[$var_flag] = $flag_status;
        $invalidate_cache = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
  
  if ($invalidate_cache) {
    $cachetag = "user:{$user_to_flag->id()}";
    Cache::invalidateTags([$cachetag]);
  }
}
```

Maybe there's a better hook to call that cache invalidation like when the flag action is made.